# JSON.parse returning error

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

So this is my JSON.stringify'd return before I try to run JSON.parse

```
{"id":"2","name":"<small>L</small>(+)-Amethopterin Hydrate","class":"6.1","subclass":"","packing_group":"III","un":"2811","cas":"133073-73-1","poisons":"","hazardous":"Yes","restricted":"No","epa":"","added_by":"0","carcinogen":null},
{"id":"3","name":"(+)-Biotin 4-Nitrophenyl ester","class":"","subclass":"","packing_group":"","un":"","cas":"33755-53-2","poisons":"","hazardous":"No","restricted":"No","epa":"","added_by":"0","carcinogen":null},
{"id":"4","name":"(+)-Biotin N-hydroxysuccinimide ester","class":"","subclass":"","packing_group":"","un":"","cas":"35013-72-0","poisons":"","hazardous":"No","restricted":"No","epa":"","added_by":"0","carcinogen":null}
```

When I try to JSON.parse I get `Unexpected end of JSON input`. And I can't access it as a JSON object because it will say `can't define id` or something to that extent.

```
JSON.parse(this.searchService.searchJson(this.php_url));
```

`this.searchService.searchJson(this.php_url)` is basically what my JSON string is. Gives error as mentioned above.

Also if I just try to stringify 1 of the 3 elements, it'll give me `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Calling function:

```
searchJson(url: any): any 
{   
    let items: any = []; 
    let new_data: any = []; 
    $.getJSON(url , 
        function(data)
        {   
            let temp_items: any = {}; 
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function (key, val)
            {   
                new_data.push(JSON.stringify(val));
            }); 
        }); 
    return new_data;
}
```

Comment: Mind showing us the parse code?

Comment: @TheLazySloth Updated it. What's returned is basically an array of stringified stuff.

Comment: That is 3 objects written in commas.. It should be an array or something.. https://jsfiddle.net/c8743h70/

Comment: Entered the JSON at JSONLint.com and it showed an error. Added it in a [ ] and the errors disappeared. Give that a shot?

Comment: @echonax The thing is... I'm pretty sure they're in an array, I'll update with my calling function

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap it with `[]` because that is an array of objects:

```
const data = [{"id":"2","name":"<small>L</small>(+)-Amethopterin Hydrate","class":"6.1","subclass":"","packing_group":"III","un":"2811","cas":"133073-73-1","poisons":"","hazardous":"Yes","restricted":"No","epa":"","added_by":"0","carcinogen":null}, {"id":"3","name":"(+)-Biotin 4-Nitrophenyl ester","class":"","subclass":"","packing_group":"","un":"","cas":"33755-53-2","poisons":"","hazardous":"No","restricted":"No","epa":"","added_by":"0","carcinogen":null}, {"id":"4","name":"(+)-Biotin N-hydroxysuccinimide ester","class":"","subclass":"","packing_group":"","un":"","cas":"35013-72-0","poisons":"","hazardous":"No","restricted":"No","epa":"","added_by":"0","carcinogen":null}]
```

`console.log(data);` will return `[Object, Object, Object]`

or if you wanna process as a JSON string you should do this:

```
const data = '[{"id":"2","name":"<small>L</small>(+)-Amethopterin Hydrate","class":"6.1","subclass":"","packing_group":"III","un":"2811","cas":"133073-73-1","poisons":"","hazardous":"Yes","restricted":"No","epa":"","added_by":"0","carcinogen":null}, {"id":"3","name":"(+)-Biotin 4-Nitrophenyl ester","class":"","subclass":"","packing_group":"","un":"","cas":"33755-53-2","poisons":"","hazardous":"No","restricted":"No","epa":"","added_by":"0","carcinogen":null}, {"id":"4","name":"(+)-Biotin N-hydroxysuccinimide ester","class":"","subclass":"","packing_group":"","un":"","cas":"35013-72-0","poisons":"","hazardous":"No","restricted":"No","epa":"","added_by":"0","carcinogen":null}]'
```

`JSON.parse(data)` will return too `[Object, Object, Object]`

Comment: when I console.log(data) it returns me `[Object {id="2", ...}, Object {id="3", name="(+)-Biotin 4-Nitrophenyl ester", ...}, Object {id="4", ...}]` so it's in a JSON format, but I can't access it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the calling function to this:

```
searchAjax(url: any): any
{   
    let new_data: any;
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json", 
        async: false

    }).responseText;
}
```

The most likely cause was that my variable was that my variable was null at the time of being called because of async.

Answer (score 1):

```
file Nmae: self.json
    [
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "<small>L</small>(+)-Amethopterin Hydrate",
            "class": "6.1",
            "subclass": "",
            "packing_group": "III",
            "un": "2811",
            "cas": "133073-73-1",
            "poisons": "",
            "hazardous": "Yes",
            "restricted": "No",
            "epa": "",
            "added_by": "0",
            "carcinogen": null
          },
          {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "(+)-Biotin 4-Nitrophenyl ester",
            "class": "",
            "subclass": "",
            "packing_group": "",
            "un": "",
            "cas": "33755-53-2",
            "poisons": "",
            "hazardous": "No",
            "restricted": "No",
            "epa": "",
            "added_by": "0",
            "carcinogen": null
          },
          {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "(+)-Biotin N-hydroxysuccinimide ester",
            "class": "",
            "subclass": "",
            "packing_group": "",
            "un": "",
            "cas": "35013-72-0",
            "poisons": "",
            "hazardous": "No",
            "restricted": "No",
            "epa": "",
            "added_by": "0",
            "carcinogen": null
          }
        ]
     $(document).ready(function($) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'self.json',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
            })
            .done(function(respose) {
                for (var i = 0; i < respose.length; i++) {
                    resText = respose[i].id+' '+respose[i].name+' '+ respose[i].class+' '+respose[i].subclass;
                    console.log(resText);
                };
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log("complete");
            });

        });
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Turns out that because I was doing ajax, the variable was null when it was displaying :\

Comment: Using jQuery Ajax

Comment: yeah, I made an answer